# Alias to open file on Windows using CygWin

Tags: windows, maven, command, cygwin, execute

I have a windows machine with CygWin installed on it. I do not hold any admin privileges, so, forget about changing environment variables which apply to all user and etc...

Scenario:

When I execute CygWin and type the following command to execute Maven, it works perfectly:

```
/cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn
```

However, when I create the file .profile as below:

```
alias mvn="cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn"
```

After restarting CygWing and executing the command "mvn", the following message is sent: **No such file or directory**.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any of you who may have the same problem, the way I solved this was basically adding a "sh" at the beginning of the command:

elias mvn="sh /cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn"

Cheers.

Comment: It looks like your original alias was wrong - it should have been: `alias mvn="/cygdrive/c/maven/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn"` and probably put into .bashrc rather than .profile.